# VSC fail to connect to ssh server

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I used the VSC SSH remote to connect to the ssh server. However, I can not successfully connect to the server. the error is as follows.

```
[23:59:48.603] > 58b9fd3bf33f: running
[23:59:48.604] stderr> bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
[23:59:48.604] stderr> bash: line 1: `  fi'
[23:59:48.604] stderr> function: Command not found.
[23:59:48.604] stderr> Bad : modifier in $ (-).
[23:59:48.604] stderr> fi: Command not found.
[23:59:48.604] stderr> found_glibc: Undefined variable.
[23:59:48.604] stderr> OAD: Command not found.
[23:59:48.605] stderr> then: Command not found.
[23:59:48.605] stderr> fail_with_exitcode: Command not found.
[23:59:48.605] > Already attempted local download, failing
[23:59:48.608] stderr> ALLOW_CLIENT_DOWNLOAD: Undefined variable.
[23:59:48.609] stderr> Unmatched `.
```

I am not sure where the error comes from. Does anyone have any idea where I can start to solve this question?